Solve Error: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o40.load.: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/BsonValue
In the Spark Session, I am trying to connect Mongodb through remote connection string and passing uri and connector jar file as config during SparkSession.builder. Here is code of Session.
spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName("ReadFromMongoDB") \
 .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "C:\\spark\\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3-scala2.13\\jars\\mongo-spark-connector_2.12-10.1.0.jar") \
  .config("spark.mongodb.read.connection.uri", "mongodb://prod-read:jP87#45H@rgfserds45@35.150.174.139:27017/project")\
    .getOrCreate()

After that, creating object that store the read data from collection from Mongodb connection where it throws error. Give code and error thrown.
    connection_string = "mongodb://prod-read:jP87#45H@r!FI45@35.170.184.139:27017/whimstay-prod"  # Replace with your details
database = "project-read"
collection = "test"

df = spark.read.format("mongodb") \
.option("spark.mongodb.input.uri", connection_string)\
.option("database",database)\
.option("collection",collection)\
.load()


Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o47.load. :
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/BsonValue    at
com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.MongoTableProvider.inferSchema(MongoTableProvider.java:62)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Utils$.getTableFromProvider(DataSourceV2Utils.scala:90)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Utils$.loadV2Source(DataSourceV2Utils.scala:140)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$1(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:283)   at
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:208)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:172)
at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
Method)   at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)    at
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842) Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bson.BsonValue  at
java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at
java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)

Can anyone encountered similar error and solved help to resolve this error or anyone with spark knowledge knows
